how to do google login in tutor mfe sign in page
I want to do sign up and sign in using google in tutor mfe . can anyone help me on this?
I set the below two value as True in tutor_plugins/myplugin.py but it is not working
ENABLE_COMBINED_LOGIN_REGISTRATION = True
ENABLE_THIRD_PARTY_AUTH = True


Firstly you need to create google secret-key and ID-
https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20Console%20Credentials%20page.,to%20add%20a%20new%20secret.
Create plugin of google credential for configuration.

=> mkdir -p "$(tutor plugins printroot)"
=> touch "$(tutor plugins printroot)/third-party-auth.py"

copy and paste below contents in file.
name: third-party-auth
version: 1.0.0
patches:
  common-env-features: |
    "ENABLE_THIRD_PARTY_AUTH": true
  openedx-auth: |
    "SOCIAL_AUTH_OAUTH_SECRETS": {"google-oauth2": "client-secret-from-google"}
  lms-env: |
    "THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_BACKENDS": ["social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2"]

Then, go to “Provider Configuration (OAuth)” in your Django admin panel:

Home › Third-party authentication › Provider Configuration (OAuth)
URL: admin/third_party_auth/oauth2providerconfig/
Click “ADD PROVIDER CONFIGURATION (OAUTH)” to add your provider.

We use these settings, but your might be slightly different.

Icon class: fa-google
Skip registration form
Skip email verification
Send welcome email
Visible
Backend name: google-oauth2
Client ID: Enter client ID from the OAuth2 provider
Client Secret: (leave blank! The value is in the plugin.)

Use the “Enabled” checkbox at the top of the page to enable or disable the OAuth2 login button.
That’s it!
